# Where to activate menu trails?

Tags: routes

I want the menu tab to be active for children of certain page that is listed with on of the menu tabs.

|HOME|Research|Contact Us

Everything in /research/whatever links,

will activate the Research tab

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the version of Drupal you're using. That helps!